# TabBarItem background color of selected item in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

How can I change background color of selected tabBarItem to other color? To red like on my attached image

[image]

Comment: Be more descriptive !

Comment: i just don't recognised what you wants???will you please elaborate...

Comment: @lGor please explain your problem.

Comment: I need to change background color of selected tabBarItem, like red color on my image

Comment: You can create IBAction for every navigationBarItem and on selection of navigation bar button you can change tint color of navigationItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to provide your Image on selected tab.

Just make subclass of `UITabBarController`, and assign it to your root tabbar controller. You can set `setSelectionIndicatorImage` property of currently selected Tab from `viewDidLoad()` method of `UITabBarController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar ;
     [tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_active_option_bkg4_default.png"]];  
}
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: can I change it not to image but to UIColor?

Comment: You can try tint color, but till I know, there is no direct way to change the  SelectionIndicator color of tabbar.